# How to differentiate between a click and swipe with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mobile, click, swipe

I have a UI that if you're using a mouse, you can click on an item and it expands.

But on mobile devices, I need to detect if they are actually swiping instead of clicking so items don't accidentally expand with tapped and swiped.

I'm using jQuery (though not jQuery Mobile at this point).

So how can I differentiate between the two on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the whole point of jQuery Mobile- adding support for swipe and pinch gestures.  AFAIK, plain jQuery doesn't have that capability.

Comment: Okay, so assuming jQuery Mobile is needed...how do I say "expand this on click but NOT on swipe"...that's the question.

Comment: You would attach the action you want to a click event instead of a swipe event.  If the user swipes (as defined by the device) then the click event won't fire.

Comment: Ultimately this just seems overkill. jQuery Mobile seems to force a lot of things (like AJAX loading all pages...what the heck???). I ultimately just want touch and swipe detection...not an entire framework that changes how my pages work.